Proving a Superfunction Identity
I am trying to figure out the proof of the identity given between equations (1.11.7) and (1.11.8) in ref. [1], i.e.
\begin{align}
    \Phi'(e^{-K}\,z\,e^K)=e^{-K}\Phi'(z) \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $z=(x,\theta)$ is a supercoordinate, $\Phi'$ is a supersmooth function, and $K$ is a differential operator (given in eq. (1.11.3) in ref. [1]): $$K=K^M(z)\partial_M = K^m(x,\theta)\partial_m + K^\mu(x,\theta)\partial_\mu\,\tag{1.11.3}$$
with $x^m$ being a bosonic spacetime coordinate and $\theta^\mu$ a fermionic coordinate.
I wonder if the identity given in the first line of eq. (1.11.7) in ref. [1], i.e.
\begin{align}
    e^{-K}\,\Psi(z)\,e^K= (e^{-K} \Psi(z)) \tag{1.11.7}
\end{align}
where $\Psi(z)$ is an arbitrary superfunction, along with the fact that $\Phi'(z)$ is a supersmooth function, has been used to arrive at eq. (1). I cannot clearly see how to prove eq. (1). Any idea how to prove it?
[1] Ideas and Methods of Supersymmetry and Supergravity by Ioseph L. Buchbinder and Sergei M. Kuzenko.

Those who are downvoting this question, would you mind stating your reasons for doing so?


OP's problem is presumably mainly caused by an ambiguous notation for how far to the right a 1st-order differential operator (DO)/vector field $K$ act, cf. e.g. this related Phys.SE post.

E.g. the extra parentheses in eq. (1.11.7) are meant to denote that the operators don't act further to the right:
$$\begin{align}\Psi((e^{-K}z))
~\stackrel{\dagger}{=}~&\Psi((e^{-K}ze^K))\cr
~\stackrel{\S}{=}~&\Psi((e^{-[K,\cdot]}z))\cr
~\stackrel{\ddagger}{=}~&\Psi(e^{-[K,\cdot]}z)\cr
~\stackrel{\S}{=}~&\Psi(e^{-K}ze^K)\cr
~\stackrel{\$}{=}~&e^{-K}\Psi(z)e^K\cr
~\stackrel{\S}{=}~&e^{-[K,\cdot]}\Psi(z)\cr
~\stackrel{\ddagger}{=}~&(e^{-[K,\cdot]}\Psi(z))\cr
~\stackrel{\S}{=}~&(e^{-K}\Psi(z)e^K)\cr
~\stackrel{\dagger}{=}~&(e^{-K}\Psi(z)).\end{align} \tag{1.11.7}$$


References:

I.L. Buchbinder and S.M. Kuzenko, Ideas and Methods of Supersymmetry and Supergravity - Or a Walk Through Superspace, 1998; Section 1.11.


$^{\dagger}$ Here is used that the DO has no 0th-order term.
$^{\ddagger}$ Here is used that the adjoint action with a 1st-order DO is a 0th-order DO.
$^{\S}$ Hadamard formula/Campbell's identity.
$^{\$}$ Here is used that $\Psi$ is a sufficiently nice function.

Is there a proof showing that if $\Psi$ is a sufficiently nice function then $\Psi(e^{-K}ze^K)=e^{-K}\Psi(z)e^K$?

Hi Susan. Yes. E.g. do you see how it is proven if $\Psi$ is a polynomial?

Hi Qmechanic, yes, I do. Would it be correct to assume that all sufficiently nice functions are polynomials?

No, next extend to larger classes of functions by taking limits.

Is such a proof shown somewhere already?

Without a doubt, although I don't have an appropriate reference handy.
